# How should we tag Ratchet & Clank: All 4 One?

Tags: discussion, tags

This is yet another of the greater-than-25-character games, in that [ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-all-4-one) doesn't quite fit, and as mentioned below, we can't use ampersands in tags ... how should we abbreviate this in a single tag? I don't think it'll ever be identified as Ratchet & Clank 10 or anything like that.

Is [ratchet-clank-all-4-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-clank-all-4-one) reasonable? Should we try something that preserves the ratchet-and-clank part?

Comment: Hm. No Ampersands in tags?

Comment: Right. They're just removed.

Comment: So the issue is having to use "and" rather than "&". I wasn't sure why the 25 character limit was coming up. Now I've got ya.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I'll edit to clarify - an example would probably help.

Comment: I find it really sad that people here are only talking about Ratchet & Clank after A4O is released... there were only **two** questions in the entire main Gaming site about the entire series before A4O came out. One of them is mine, and the other is apparently gone :(

Comment: Based on the answers given, I think the question itself should also be rephrased with a broader scope. Not sure how I'll edit it without ruining the content, though.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro, there are already questions about [the fixed 25-character limit](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/1037/8366) and [using acronyms only when necessary](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/91/8366); I was wondering how to apply those rules here, although I could have added those links for clarity.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro, with respect to games in the series, feel free to come up with good questions about other R&C games and add them yourself! Adding quality questions about older games is perfectly fine ... and it might prompt others to get those games out and maybe ask questions of their own. (Also, both those questions are still around; look for `rnc-crack-in-time` for the other one.)

Comment: @Dave DuPlantis: You meant `rnc-a-crack-in-time` :) http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnc-a-crack-in-time

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro, yep, sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this is a series, I recommend using an acronym.  While [ratchet-clank-all-4-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-clank-all-4-one) fits, [ratchet-clank-tools-of-destruction](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-clank-tools-of-destruction), [ratchet-clank-quest-for-booty](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-clank-quest-for-booty), and [ratchet-clank-crack-in-time](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-clank-crack-in-time) definitely don't.

A good example of acronyms is the Command and Conquest games, which use cnc at the start of games with subtitles.  Even then, [rnc-tools-of-destruction](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rnc-tools-of-destruction) barely fits.

Comment: I think this works better for the series; I had doubts about searching by R&C, given that I think that C&C is well-known by that acronym, but looking for R&C in Google does bring up "ratchet and clank ..." searches as similar. There are, as of yet, only two games in the series with questions: if it becomes awkward, we can always revisit.

Comment: @Dave: Yes, most Ratchet fans (myself included) abbreviate it as R&C. They also abbreviate the names of each installment in the series too. For example, R&C: GC for Going Commando, R&CF: TOD for Ratchet & Clank Future: Tools of Destruction and R&C: A4O for All 4 One.

Comment: @Dave: ... but abbreviating the installment names in the tags is probably also a bad idea.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro, yeah, I think what we want is to keep as much spelled out as possible and only abbreviate when necessary. That will help people less familiar with the series find questions for it.

Answer (score 3):

[ratchet-clank-all-4-one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-clank-all-4-one) is fine. Removing "**and**" should have no impact on our SEO with Google, which is one of the reasons tags exist in the first place.

Comment: 1: You misspelled Ratchet. 2. You have to make sure this works with all the other games in the series: Tools of Destruction, Quest For Booty, and Crack in Time to name the 3 most recent before this one.

Comment: Removing the word "and" makes it inconsistent with the existing [ratchet-and-clank] tag, even if it does save characters...

Answer (score 0):

Considering the "4" in the title, perhaps it can be used as a word break rather than dashes?  (i.e. [ratchet-and-clank-all4one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ratchet-and-clank-all4one))  It fits, and doesn't cut any of the words in the title.