# Synonym requests - gta-x > grand-theft-auto-x

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Can these be made synonyms?

- [gta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta) > [grand-theft-auto](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto) (or possibly with a '1' appended)
- [gta-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-2) > [grand-theft-auto-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-2)
- [gta-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-3) > [grand-theft-auto-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-3)
- [gta-san-andreas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-san-andreas) > [grand-theft-auto-sa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-sa) (For the reasons given on [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5330/28182) answer)
- [gta-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-4) > [grand-theft-auto-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-4)

Added for completeness, although there isn't any questions for this game yet

- [gta-vice-city](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-vice-city) > [grand-theft-auto-vc](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-vc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yea to [gta-4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-4): tag renamed.
- Yes to [gta-san-andreas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-san-andreas), which is now *the target* for [grand-theft-auto-sa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-sa).
- Nay to the rest for lack of questions. I'd be especially nervous about having a [gta](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta) tag.

Comment: that's why I said possibly with a '1' appended, as to avoid a "blanket" tag that people will assume applies to the series. Do you reckon this would be better?