# Rename [gta-*] → [grand-theft-auto-*] to be consistent with other tags in the series

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

There are a number of tags for the *[Grand Theft Auto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto)* series, such as [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5), [grand-theft-auto-san-andreas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-san-andreas), [grand-theft-auto-5-ifruit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5-ifruit), etc. However, this is inconsistent since there are a number of tags in the series that have a prefix of `gta-`, likely due to the former restriction of 25 characters.

In order to be more consistent, I'd recommend that we rename the following tags to be in line with the other tags in the series (keeping the old tags as synonyms).

- [gta-chinatown-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-chinatown-wars) → [grand-theft-auto-chinatown-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-chinatown-wars)
- [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online) → [grand-theft-auto-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-online)

  - For reference: this was [previously agreed](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7761/47878) to be a separate tag from [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5)
- [gta-creator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-creator) → [grand-theft-auto-content-creator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-content-creator) (referring to [this](http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Content_Creator))

  - Maybe merge with [grand-theft-auto-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-online) instead?
- [gta-vice-city](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-vice-city) → [grand-theft-auto-vice-city](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-vice-city)
- [gta-vice-city-stories](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-vice-city-stories) → [grand-theft-auto-vice-city-stories](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-vice-city-stories)

This would also be consistent with [Synonym requests - gta-x > grand-theft-auto-x](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5680/47878), which was a previous meta topic about renaming the tags that existed at the time.

---

Related: [Tag synonym request: Grand Theft Auto games, Saints Row IV](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12881/47878) requesting tags for numbered games like [grand-theft-auto-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-5) to be renamed with Roman numerals to match their official spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These renames have been done:

- [gta-chinatown-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-chinatown-wars) → [grand-theft-auto-chinatown-wars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-chinatown-wars)
- [gta-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-online) → [grand-theft-auto-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-online)
- [gta-creator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-creator) → [grand-theft-auto-content-creator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-content-creator)
- [gta-vice-city](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-vice-city) → [grand-theft-auto-vice-city](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-vice-city)
- [gta-vice-city-stories](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-vice-city-stories) → [grand-theft-auto-vice-city-stories](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grand-theft-auto-vice-city-stories)